# Deploy Main and Admin app to the same domain where admin can be used from domain/admin route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel, nx-monorepo

I am working on nxMonorepo next js project where I have 2 apps using next js,

**1. Main application**

**2. Admin panel**

I have deployed both applications on Vercel which is working fine.

but I want to use the main app and admin app in a single domain like

main app : [www.xyz-vercel.com](http://www.xyz-vercel.com)
admin app: [www.xyz-vercel.com/admin](http://www.xyz-vercel.com/admin)  using tailwind css

so for that, I created another repo and created vercel.json over there, and added the below configuration in that vercel.json

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/admin/",
      "destination": "https://xyz-admin.vercel.app/"
    },
    {
      "source": "/admin/:match*",
      "destination": "https://xyz-admin.app/:match*"
    },
    {
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "https://xyz-main.vercel.app/"
    },
    {
      "source": "/:match*",
      "destination": "https://xyz-main.vercel.app/:match*"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is working when I try to use the main application but when I try to redirect to /admin/ it loads the HTML content but not the assets like CSS, Images and JS files.

Comment: you might need to add  `<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">` to the index.html server at `/admin`

Comment: @Azzy,, CSS and JS file is getting called like below,
https://xyz-vercel.com/_next/static/chunks/main-app-955b9566c2b02790.js
but the actually CSS / JS is present at 
https://xyz-admin.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/main-app-955b9566c2b02790.js